# change the transform attribute in D3.js calendar view

Tags: javascript, d3.js, calendar

[image]i am referring D3.js calendar view   http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318.

everything is working properly. but the issue is my data is something like:

[{"Date":"04-26-2014 17:39:29","Available":"10","Open":"90","Low":"80","High":"90","RGraph2":[{"Date":"04-29-2014 17:39:29","Available":"10","Open":"90","Low":"80","High":"90","RGraph2":null},{"Date":"04-28-2014 17:39:29","Available":"10","Open":"90","Low":"80","High":"90","RGraph2":null}]},{"Date":"04-24-2014 17:39:29","Available":"10","Open":"90","Low":"80","High":"90","RGraph2":null}]

it's in json format. When calendar g has drawn i wanted all the Rgraph2 (say sub calendar) calendar position in a bit right side. it can be done if i find out the g transform attribute and change the transform attribute. any body help me out.

Comment: I don't understand what the structure of your data has to do with the transform on a `<g>` element.  Can you more clearly describe what you're trying to achieve and how it is different from the original (maybe create a picture of what you want it to look like)?

Comment: If you see the data in json stack viewer you will see two arrays. there is a array named Rgraph2 inside array one so i want that calendar position right to the 1st array. I added the picture above along with my query. clearly, the first calendar is 1st array, 2nd calendar is Rgraph2 of 1st array (part of first array) and third calendar is 2nd array.

Comment: Thanks for the edit -- that helps me understand what you're trying to do.  But I'm not sure why you need to figure out an existing transform value -- just create a child `<g>` element for the sub-array, add a transform attribute to it, and then position all the rectangles within that group with the exact same code as the main visualization.

Comment: i don't know how to create calendar for child array. this is the issue. I am not able to figure out from their given d3.js calendar example.